# How to select first or last date of range in react-dates DayPickerRangeController?

Tags: react-dates

I would like users to be able to select the start date or end date of a range of dates defined by the 'isDayBlocked' prop - is this possible at all? The use-case being, using Airbnb for example, is June 7th to June 14th are blocked, a user should still be able to select June 1st to June 7th for their booking.
Many thanks,
Matt